# Creating Table that has multiple Foreign Keys in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to create a table of ENCOUNTER entity. I have successfully created all the foreign key tables associated with this table, but when I try to run it on Oracle Database Express Edition 11g, it's keep giving the following error message, and I cannot find any error. `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` Below is the command syntax.

```
CREATE TABLE ENCOUNTER (
ENCT_ID VARCHAR2(25) PRIMARY KEY,
ENCT_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
PT_MRN NUMBER NOT NULL,
ENCT_BP VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
ENCT_WT NUMBER(3,2) NOT NULL,
ENCT_TEMP NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
ACCT_ID VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
PHX_ID VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_PATIENT FOREIGN KEY (PT_MRN) REFERENCES PATIENT(PT_MRN)
CONSTRAINT FK_ACCOUNT FOREIGN KEY (ACCT_ID) REFERENCES ACCOUNT(ACCT_ID)
CONSTRAINT FK_PTHISTORY FOREIGN KEY (PHX_ID) REFERENCES PTHISTORY(PHX_ID));
```

Answer (score 9):

I believe you are missing commas after each constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE ENCOUNTER (
ENCT_ID VARCHAR2(25) PRIMARY KEY,
ENCT_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
PT_MRN NUMBER NOT NULL,
ENCT_BP VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
ENCT_WT NUMBER(3,2) NOT NULL,
ENCT_TEMP NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
ACCT_ID VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
PHX_ID VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_PATIENT FOREIGN KEY (PT_MRN) REFERENCES PATIENT(PT_MRN),
CONSTRAINT FK_ACCOUNT FOREIGN KEY (ACCT_ID) REFERENCES ACCOUNT(ACCT_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_PTHISTORY FOREIGN KEY (PHX_ID) REFERENCES PTHISTORY (PHX_ID));
```

Comment: Not *each* constraint, rather all but the last one.